# Stop window.event with Javascript window.confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a confirm box come up when the viewer tries to close the window, that allows the user to stay on the current page (by click Cancel), or continue closing the window (by click OK).

My code is as follows...

```
<script>     
    function confirm_exit(){
        var message = window.confirm("My message.");
        if (message == true) {
            // Output when OK is clicked
            window.close();
        } else {
            // Output when CANCEL is clicked
            ???????
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am not sure because either one I click closes the window. I need Cancel to remain at the current page, and OK to close the window or proceed with the users window.event.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of a [certain website with a dash](https://www.google.com/search?q="JavaScript+-+Confirm+on+page+leave") in it's name:

```
window.onbeforeunload = leaveConfirm;
function leaveConfirm() {
    var leaveThePageMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
    return leaveThePageMessage;
}​
```

This should work in all browsers (except for Opera).

Comment: @Wrikken Fortunately, Opera accounts for a very small portion of most sites' market share. Less than 1% usually, if even that much, so that should not be a major problem. In the case of Opera users, I think JS continues to run after you navigate away so you may actually be able to safely save what a user may have done on a page so they don't lose any work in Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to close?');
}
```